# Different property value for contracts

Tags: c#, .net

I have two interfaces implemented by one main class. How can i refactor my code in a way that on implementing each contract, the methods of each contract has a different value for a parameter such as DatabaseName.

Example :

1. Class1 Implements Interface1,Interface2
2. Interface1.GetData() has DatabaseName set to Database 1
3. Interface2.GetData() has DatabaseName set to Database 2

I can configure those value in the methods GetData() but i want a cleaner way of doing it.

Any pattern recommendation be that DI ,Domain driven ,even basic inheritance example which accomplishes the above is what i am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like all you need is [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```
public class Class1 : Interface1, Interface2
{
    // Note the lack of access modifier here. That's important!
    Data Interface1.GetData()
    {
        // Implementation for Interface1
    }

    Data Interface2.GetData()
    {
        // Implementation for Interface2
    }
}
```

Obviously the two methods can call a common method with a parameter to specify the database name or similar.

Comment: My mind is just blown that Jon skeet even answers newbie questions , what if i have 100 methods in both the interfaces ?

Comment: @ZohaibAmin: Then I'd be pretty worried about those interfaces being too large to start with. You only need to use explicit implementation for the methods where you want the implementations to differ though - you can mix implicit and explicit interface implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Refactoring is usually motivated by noticing a code smell and the very fact that you ended up in a situation where you have to implement 2 abstraction which expose similar functionality is the code smell**. 
Without having more understanding of the problem I might not be able to provide you a conclusive answer but with limited understanding this is what I would propose. Have 2 different concrete implementation each implementing one interface and have a factory which would be injected to client and make the client make the deliberate decision which one of these implementation is needed. In case these concrete classes share common functionality you can always abstract that into a common parent class.

```
public interface ISQLReader
    {
        string GetData();
    }

    public interface IOracleReader
    {
        string GetData();
    }

    public abstract class Reader
    {
        protected void CommonFunctionaility()
        {

        }
    }
    public class MSSQLReader : Reader, ISQLReader
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "MSSQL";
        }
    }

    public class OracleReader : Reader, IOracleReader
    {
        public string GetData()
        {
            return "Oracle";
        }
    }

    public interface IReaderFactory
    {
        OracleReader CreateOracleReader();
        MSSQLReader CreateMSSQLReader();
    }

    public class ReaderFactory : IReaderFactory
    {
        public MSSQLReader CreateMSSQLReader() => new MSSQLReader();

        public OracleReader CreateOracleReader() => new OracleReader();
    }

    public class ReaderClient
    {
        private IReaderFactory _factory;
        public ReaderClient(IReaderFactory factory)
        {
            this._factory = factory;
        }
    }
```

Explicit interface implementation is technique that should restrict usage of the functionality until the client has made and explicit cast there by making a deliberate decision.